# Powershell: errorhandling in script

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I have a script which are going to run on several local computers, but I haven't done any errorhandling in it. I have not done any errorhandling in powershell at all, so i'm a total noob here. I read something about it, but honestly I am just looking for an quick and easy answer..

Q: Is there something like a try/catch, as little code as possible to not make the script heavy weight?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, try/catch/finally is available in Powershell v2:

```
Try{
<main code here>
}
Catch{
write-host $_ #Using the reserved $_ variable which should contain the error string
}
Finally{
<clean up code here - will execute regardless>
}
```

If you're constrained to use Powershell v1 then you will have to use the trap construct.

Comment: I'm using powershell v2.
What I did with this code was paste all my script into the Try{}, and leave the catch unspecified so that it would catch all exceptions,(I thought), when I on purpose wrote a new line in the try{} "sdgsf"
I got the error message specified in the catch{}, but when I do something like: 
"$username = gc env:usernamejghc" (I wrote jiberish at the end of the command)
I get error: Get-Content : Cannot find path 'Env:\usernamejghc' because it does not exist.

I'm going to read some more on the subject, meanwhile: Any suggestions that will handle this error?

Comment: You mean $env:usernamejghc, I guess. The message exactly tells you what happens.

Comment: Yes, but why won't the catch block "catch" it? If this error escape it, I suppose other can too?

Answer (score 0):

Powershell 2.0 has try, catch and finally. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315350.aspx You can also do a more command-line oriented variation of error handling with error trapping like here: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=729515&seqNum=5